# MedusaFX elements in an Array, if editing the array, do not update screen

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm using the MedusaFX Library to get gauges for a project I'm working on. I'm using a JavaFX Application to run everything and Scene Builder to create an FXML file in order to create the layout. What I've observed is that if I do

```
    @FXML private Gauge gauge1 = new Gauge();
    gauge1.setValue(30);
```

then the gauge1 variable gets the correct value set. However, if I do

```
    @FXML private Gauge gauge1 = new Gauge();
    ArrayList<Gauge> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(gauge1);
    list.get(0).setValue(30);

    System.out.println(gauge1);
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

My output is

```
{"title":"Temperature","subTitle":"Temperature","unit":"°F","value":0.0,"minValue":0.0,"maxValue":175.0,"threshold":60.0,"minMeasuredValue":0.0,"maxMeasuredValue":0.0}
{"title":"","subTitle":"","unit":"","value":30.0,"minValue":0.0,"maxValue":100.0,"threshold":100.0,"minMeasuredValue":30.0,"maxMeasuredValue":30.0}
```

This output confuses me as it looks like the ArrayList creates a new instance of Gauge instead of modifying the one that it has within it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load an fxml file with `FXMLLoader.load()`, it will parse the file, and it will create an instance of every node it finds.

So, assuming that there is a `Gauge` node in your fxml file with `fx:id="gauge1"`, when you add this to your controller:

```
@FXML private Gauge gauge1;
```

the `FXMLLoader` will create an instance for you. You can then set a value like:

```
public void initialize() {
    gauge1.setValue(30);
}
```

But when you do:

```
@FXML private Gauge gauge1 = new Gauge();
```

what is happening is that you are actually creating a second instance: the first one is created by reflexion, just based on the `fx:id` label, and added to the scene graph by the `FXMLLoader`, while the second you create is never added to the scene graph.

Later on, you don't know what is the actual instance you are modifying. When you do the printout, probably you are accessing both objects, being that on the list the one not added to the scene graph.

So the solution is easy: don't create the second instance, and use just this:

```
@FXML private Gauge gauge1;
```